# Detect if options menu is displayed when back button is pressed

Tags: java, android

My back button is overridden for ... reasons. I've implemented a new feature, the options menu, and I need unique function calls if the back button is pressed while this options menu is up versus when it is not up. How can I discern if the menu is up when the back button is pressed? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5):

Use a `boolean`. Set it to `true` in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`. Set it to `false` in `onOptionsMenuClosed()`.